# Import file from SVN to android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, import

I have eclipse kepler where I must import project files from SVN repository as Android project. After importing this I want track files inside android project by using SVN. How do this in "normal" way?

After importing project and select "Check out as a project configured using the New Project Wizzard".

I have this incorrect structure.

I woud like to replace src and other standart files using SVN filies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Subversion plugin for Eclipse. For one of the tutorial, follow [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-subversion/).

Comment: I use this. Problem is incorect structure of imported project.